# Problem with some advanced UI

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create tables with rounded corners. I've quite a bit of XML to do this, but I have a problem.  The table is wrapping itself to the width of its inner text.  I want the entire thing to fill the parent (though I want a border around it so there is some cushion, which I have).  I can't understand why it is not when I have everything to fill_parent.  Could someone point out what is wrong?

Here's a screenshot of what I mean and a copy of my XML:

[screenshot 1](http://i34.tinypic.com/15cn6kj.png)

shape_outer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#0000FF"/>
    <corners android:radius="5px"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" /> 
</shape>
```

shape_inner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="5px"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" /> 
</shape>
```

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="47px"
        style="?android:attr/windowTitleBackgroundStyle"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="My title"
            style="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle"
            android:paddingLeft="5px" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10px"
        >
        <!-- used so we can separate two tables -->
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            >
            <!-- first table -->
            <TableRow android:paddingBottom="10px">
                <!-- outer border -->
                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:stretchColumns="1"
                    android:padding="2px"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_outer"
                    >
                    <TableRow>
                        <!-- inner whitespace -->
                        <TableLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:stretchColumns="1"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/shape_inner"
                            android:padding="10px"
                            >
                            <TableRow>
                                <!-- first row: one -->
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                                    >
                                    <TextView 
                                        android:layout_width="70px"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:text="One:"
                                        android:padding="6dip"
                                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                                    <TextView 
                                        android:id="@+id/one"
                                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:text="sadflkjaasasdfadsdsf;lkjdsal;asdj"
                                        android:padding="6dip"
                                        android:textColor="#000000"
                                        android:maxLines="1" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                            <!-- separator -->
                            <View
                                android:layout_height="1dip"
                                android:background="#FF909090" />
                            <TableRow>
                                <!-- second row: two -->
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                                    >
                                    <TextView 
                                        android:layout_width="70px"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:text="Two:"
                                        android:padding="6dip"
                                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                                    <TextView 
                                        android:id="@+id/two"
                                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:text="asdfasdasdfasdfasfasdfasgeargfsgsfd"
                                        android:padding="6dip"
                                        android:textColor="#000000"
                                        android:maxLines="1" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableLayout>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <!-- second table -->
            <TableRow>
                <!-- outer border -->
                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:stretchColumns="1"
                    android:padding="2px"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_outer"
                    >
                    <TableRow>
                        <!-- inner white space -->
                        <TableLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:stretchColumns="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/shape_inner"
                            android:padding="10px"
                            >
                            <!-- third row: Three -->
                            <TableRow>
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                                    >
                                    <TextView 
                                        android:layout_width="70px"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:text="Three:"
                                        android:padding="6dip"
                                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                                    <TextView 
                                        android:id="@+id/three"
                                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:text="asdfasfasdfasgeargfsgsfd"
                                        android:padding="6dip"
                                        android:textColor="#000000"
                                        android:singleLine="true"
                                        android:ellipsize="end" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                            <!-- separator -->
                            <View
                                android:layout_height="1dip"
                                android:background="#FF909090" />
                            <!-- second row: four -->
                            <TableRow>
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                                    >
                                    <TextView 
                                        android:layout_width="70px"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:text="Four:"
                                        android:padding="6dip"
                                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                                    <TextView 
                                        android:id="@+id/four"
                                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_column="1"
                                        android:text="aasdfasfasdfasgeargfsgsfd"
                                        android:padding="6dip"
                                        android:textColor="#000000"
                                        android:singleLine="true"
                                        android:ellipsize="end" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableLayout>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a really complicated layout.. The HeirarchyViewer, found in the tools folder, might help you debug.  You can look to see which element is causing your row to stretch beyond where you want it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It's not just that it causes the table to extend beyond the limits of the screen.  If the text is very short, the table because very narrow as well.  But nothing should be wrapping :(

Comment: I seem to have fixed it, though I don't understand why.  My outer-most TableLayout is now fill_parent, while every other Table_Layout is wrap_content.  Thank you again

Comment: I've wrapped it in a ScrollView and now I have the same probably aaaall over again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of tables was convoluted and pointless.  Here is my working XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:paddingRight="15dip"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_outer"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_inner"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dip"
                >
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="70dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="One:"
                    android:padding="6dip"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:gravity="right" />
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/one"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="6dip"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="sdklafjalfkjaslgkjafds"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:padding="10dip" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dip"
                >
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="70dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Two:"
                    android:padding="6dip"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:gravity="right" />
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/two"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="6dip"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="dsaklfajsdkldsafjsf"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

glad you fixed it, however you could accomplish the same look much easier using relative layouts.

Comment: How so?  I would then have to position the shapes and the textviews on top of each other.  Wouldn't this be an additional level of complexity?

Comment: Here's the real tough part: I'd like these tables to be dynamic.  Meaning, in my Java code I'd like to be able to add them for N things  Is it possible to achieve this?  The only thing I can think of is to use a ListView with one of these tables as a list item.  The problem is I also don't want the tables to be maxed out at 2 rows.  I want those rows to be dynamic as well.